# I'm having trouble making a batch file rename and modify a txt file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

this is my first question thing so dont judge me too hard.

I'm trying to make a batch file that inputs the PC name, User, date and time into a text (.txt) file. I want/need It to have multiple logs and only In on file.

(the text file will be in the same directory)

Here is what I have done so far and it seems to work for the first 2 (you'll see what I mean) but then it makes another file called 1. I dont know if its my laptop or if its my lack of any coding skill.

```
@echo off

:make1
if exist "1.txt" goto make2
set SomeVar=%ComputerName% %UserName% %date% %time% 
echo %SomeVar% > "1.txt"


exit


:make2

if exist "2.txt" goto make3
ren "1.txt" "2.txt"
echo %SomeVar% >> "2.txt"

exit


:make3
if exist "3.txt" goto make4
ren "2.txt" "3.txt"
echo %SomeVar% >>> "3.txt"
exit

:make4
if exist "4.txt" goto make5
ren "3.txt" "4.txt"
echo %SomeVar% >>>> "4.txt"

exit

:make5
if exist "5.txt" goto make6
ren "4.txt" "5.txt"
set SomeVar=%ComputerName% %UserName% %date% %time% 
echo %SomeVar% >>>>> "5.txt"

 exit

:make6

set SomeVar=%ComputerName% %UserName% %date% %time% 
echo %SomeVar% >>>>>> "6.txt"


pause
exit
```

I know the last one will be overwritten but i can be bothered adding heaps
(also if you have a way of making it infinite it would be greatly appreciated.)

Im making most of my stuff during class at school and I first got into batch about a year ago so sorry for the bad/crude/excessive/annoying code

Thanks, ThePolarBear

Comment: Read https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Answer (score 1):

```
> mean overwrite entire line
>> append to last line
```

you don't need to put >>>>>